# Append json into a json in groovy

Tags: json, groovy

I am newbie to groovy. My requirement is i have to append a json into a json.My code as follows:

JSON constructed by me:

```
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
   def root=builder.event{                
            type  "model_output_load_init"
            time new Timestamp(date.getTime())
            status "success"                        
        }
```

JSON from DB:

```
def json = rs.getString("status");
```

Now i have to append constructed into the JSON From DB. PLease help me to solve this.Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

My Constructed JSON:

```
{
    "event": {
        "type": "model_output_load_init",
        "time": "2015-10-01T14:08:17+0000",
        "status": "success"
    }
}
```

JSON FROM DB:

```
{
    "model_build": {
        "Initialized": {
            "Timestamp": ""
        }
    },
    "modelExec": {
        "Initialized": {
            "Timestamp": ""
        }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT NEEDED:

```
{
    "model_build": {
        "Initialized": {
            "Timestamp": ""
        }
    },
    "modelExec": {
        "Initialized": {
            "Timestamp": ""
        }
    },
    "event": {
        "type": "model_output_load_init",
        "time": "2015-10-01T14:08:17+0000",
        "status": "success"
    }

}
```

Comment: Append how?  Add to a List?  You can't have another `type` in the same object, so I assume so...

Comment: @tim_yates please see my updated post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can append to the Map generated by JsonSlurper.

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

def builder = new JsonBuilder()
def root = builder.event{                
    type  "model_output_load_init"
    time new Timestamp(date.getTime())
    status "success"                        
}

// Simulates the JSON from DB
def json = new JsonSlurper().parseText('''
{
    "model_build": {
        "Initialized": {
            "Timestamp": ""
        }
    },
    "modelExec": {
        "Initialized": {
            "Timestamp": ""
        }
    }
}''')

// Append the built JSON to the "slurped" JSON
json.event = root.event

// Re-build the JSON so it can saved as a String
new JsonBuilder(json).toPrettyString()
```

The output looks like this:

```
{
    "event": {
        "type": "model_output_load_init",
        "time": "2015-10-01T14:39:11+0000",
        "status": "success"
    },
    "modelExec": {
        "Initialized": {
            "Timestamp": ""
        }
    },
    "model_build": {
        "Initialized": {
            "Timestamp": ""
        }
    }
}
```